# Rollback to specific savepoint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following scenario (postgresql)
`my table is student(id varchar,name varchar)`.
The thing is i have 10 insert statements and savepoint after even statements and at last after 10 i have commit.The condition is that if 4th query fails in the transaction it should be rollback till 2nd and if 6th fails it should rollback till 4nd .how to know which query failed in a transaction and how to rollback to that specific savepoint?

Comment: INSERT ....; SAVEPOINT foo; UPDATE ....; ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT foo, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-savepoint.html, or you forgot to specify programming language

Comment: Does it have to rollback 2 commands back or only the 4th and 6th have this constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs:   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-rollback-to.html

It's simple.  you just roll back to the savepoint you want, which remains valid and you can roll back to it again if you need to....